# How to switch len [ ] positions of a string in a loop that compares input with the string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Basically , I have a txt file with words. One of these words is randomly selected , the string len is counted and an input asking to guess the first letter is looped times the lenght of the string.

Problem is i dont know how to skip to the next letter [1]so on, so that it isnt stuck asking for the first letter.

```
for i in range(len(word)):

        i += len(word)



        first = input(which)

        if word[0] == first[0]:

            print('The first letter is ',first)

            guess = first

            print(guess)

            which += 1



        elif print('Wrong!',first, 'is not the letter'):
            which -= 1
            counter += 1

            if counter != 6:
                print('Game Over')
                game()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to ask an arbitrary number of times, a `while` loop might be better:

```
idx = 0
counter = 0
LOSS = 6
while idx < len(word) and counter < LOSS:
    first = input("Guess the next letter of the word: ")
    if first[0] == word[idx]:
        # correct guess
        print(f"Correct, the letter is {word[idx]}!")
        # move on to the next index
        idx += 1
    else:
        # incorrect guess
        print(f"Wrong! {first[0]} is not the next letter.")
        # increment win-loss counter
        counter += 1
    # then, repeat indefinitely until either the index exceeds the length of the word,
    # or the counter exceeds 6
# when one of those things happens, we can check if the user won or lost:
if counter >= LOSS:
    print("Game Over")
else:
    print("Congratulations, you win!")
```